# ChromeCast switching between App Ids and Receivers from Sender

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm building an Android Sender ChromeCast app that will test several different receivers. I have made an app that has an *appId*  / receiver selector activity, and upon selection it launches a new activity that connects to the ChromeCast.

I am using the Cast Companion Library version 2.7.3.

On initial launch of the app, it connects to the first *appId* / receiver perfectly, but unfortunately, being able to switch the *appId* from a single activity has proven to be difficult.

It seems that no matter what actions I take, the first *appId* / receiver remains persistent, even after disconnecting, going back to the homescreen, and restarting the app.

I've tried:

1. Launching an initial Activity that has an an app Id selector that launches a new ChromeCast sender activity, and when back is pressed, it set all instances of any cast related Objects to null.
2. Modifying the Cast Companion Library to allow my UI app to access     `stopReconnectionService()` and `stopNotificationService()`.
3. In conjunction with the previous steps, implementing the `teardown()` method found [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender#error-handling).
4. Again in conjunction with previous steps, calling `stopApplication` and setting `setStopOnDisconnect(true)`.

I've only been able to get it to work using `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` and I just think there must be  a better way.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't explain what issue you are running into. As for what you want to do, is it correct that you want to have one single app that starts the receiver with appId1, then stops that and then starts the receiver with appId2, then stops that, and so on, and all of them on the same cast device?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I would like to have one single app that starts a receiver with appId1, stops it, then switches to a receiver with appId2, all on the same ChromeCast device. It's OK if it involves restarting the app. I will update the question according to your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: I still can't see where the issue is. Cast.CastApi.launchApplication() takes a appId argument so each time when you leave the previous application (leaveApplication()), then you can call launchApplication() with the new appId and that should launch the new receiver application. If you are doing this and it is not working, then we need to see your code.

Comment: Ok I will try this thank you